# Login form, how to login using 3 tables in one login form?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, visual-studio, winforms

i'm creating a login page for my windows application in windows form app(.net framework) & C#, using visual studio 2019.

My login page has 2 text boxes for username and password, a login button and register button to switch to register form with some required field validations on each control.

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and have 3 tables in there, Student, Admin, and Coordinator, each one has columns for their details such as UserId, Username, Password, Email, Age, Gender, Address, Contact.

What i would like to do is when the user presses the submit button, it checks the student table for the username and its password, if its not there, it checks the Coordinator, then the admins. If its not in any of them, it gives an error that the login failed.

I put an SQLCommand on the page that pulls the username and password from the student table where they are equal to the textboxes text.

Do i need to add 3 sqlcommands to page for each table? Or need to create 3 login form for each user?

My code works but its only check Admin table, not Coordinator and Student tables
Is there a better way to do it??

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bool valid = true;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please! Enter Username and Password.", "Login Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    valid = false;
                }
                if (valid)
                {
                    String UserType = null;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select usertype from Admin where UserName = '" + uName.Text + "' and Password = '" + password.Text + "' ", con);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    Boolean records = dr.HasRows;

                    if (records)
                    {

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            UserType = dr[0].ToString();
                        }

                        if (UserType.Equals("Admin"))
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("Admin Just Logged In, Welcome!", "Login Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            frmAdmin frmA = new frmAdmin();
                            frmA.Show();
                            this.Hide();

                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!", "User Login Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!" + ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Your code is **seriously** flawed, as it suffers from SQL Injection. Try putting your username as `' OR 1=1;--` and you'll be surprised what happens. You **must** fix that. Also, your code **strongly** *implies* you are storing plain text passwords. **never** do that. Hash and salt your passwords.

Comment: Extract Credentials from the 3 Tables into an own Credentials Table link the other 3 Tables to the Credentials table and then do only check against that Table. Maybe add a Role column to the Credentials Table for easy distinguish the roles of your users. And do what @Larnu says.

Comment: I imagine this is just an experiment/learning process for you, but I do strongly agree with Larnu. It would be good for you from the get-go to at least make yourself aware why these things are bad (check "OWASP top 10")

Comment: @Ralf sounds like this should be an answer? :)

Comment: Use a SQL Join : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15  I would test the join using SQL Se4rver Management Studio to get syntax correct.  Then put the query string into c#.

Comment: @Xerillio. Nah i want him to get him thinking. Do i realy need 3 Tables? Or is an extra column enough. Better than throwing a solution at him.

Comment: Best DB design is to have one `User` table with everyone in it. Either have a `Type` column, or separate `Admin` etc tables with FK back to `User`. Other issues with your code: **1.** Risk of SQL injection, you should use proper parameters **2.** You are caching your connection object, you should dispose all objects **3.** Don't block the thread with code that waits for the user while the connection is open **4.** Don't store plain-text passwords **5.** No need to check `HasRows` because `while(Read)` sorts that out. You probably want `ExecuteScalar` anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think you need  1 table instead of 3 you can call this table a Users table.
For roles like admin, user, the coordinator you can create another table like UserRoles.
(This will save you the need to create additional tables for each incoming roles)

So you can check one table if the user exists or not.
Please keep passwords hashed and have a read about SQL Injection.

Users Table

| Id | UserTypeId | UserName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | admin@noemail.com |
| 1 | 2 | coordinator@noemail.com |
| 1 | 3 | student@noemail.com |

Users Roles

| Id | UserRole | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | admin |
| 2 | coordinator | coordinator role |
| 3 | student | student role |
| 4 | teacher | teacher role |

Comment: Yeah you right, but in my case i have use data grid view show those 3 users separately in 3 forms. That's why i can't use one table. Or else i have to use 3 login forms for each user type. Is foreign key gonna works, connecting 3 tables each other? I don't know maybe i'm wrong just asking.

Comment: It is so easy to write a SQL script that can filter user types. I did this sample for you. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dqtsACfGkg2P6eDNNcRbD7/0

Comment: In your SQL DB if you keep username as a unique key you can determine the role of the logged-in user.

If you keep the logged-in user role (i.e admin) you can write your business logic which can fill the data grid according to users' authorization level. (i.e admin has a level to see all users)

Comment: You need a `Role` table also, `UserRole` should be just a junction table

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way i know.
But right now the fastest way to solve your problem is using a combo box or some radio buttons and ask the user what is your role and use user selection.